# Do we need military-defense tag when we have warfare?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there any need for having two different tags, which, IMHO, relate to the same thing? I don't have the required rep in [military-defense](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-defense) to suggest a synonym to the more general [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare).

Comment: I'm pretty sure, someone who, in the WB scope, is a specialist of warfare will be good enough in military defense, wouldn't s/he?

Comment: And we should also have civil-war as a synonym of warfare?

Answer (score 3):

Someone who is an expert in [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) should probably be able to provide good answers to questions about [military-defense](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-defense). If party A exercises [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) against party B, then it stands to reason that party B will need to exercise [military-defense](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-defense) unless party B is prepared to immediately and unconditionally surrender to party A (which, come to think of it, is also a defense strategy, though unlikely to work well in the long term). Hence, the two are merely opposite sides of the same coin, but one can reasonably expect people to look for one or the other depending on the focus of the particular question they are writing.

**Sounds to me like a good candidate for a tag synonym.**

I certainly *do not* see any need for an additional, different tag for [military-defense](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-defense) which is *distinct* from [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare), as we currently have. **The two can probably be merged** (and, in fact, will need to be, if we want to establish the synonym).

Comment: What do you think about making the synonym "military" rather than "military-defense"?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Military forces, particularly in fantasy worlds, can easily be put to use in situations other than warfare. I'm not sure that would be an appropriate synonym.